# git command pushes as wrong user

Tags: git, github

I have read through multiple questions addressing this problem, but none of the solutions work for me. I have changed the `user.name` and `user.email` of my local repository, yet when pushing it doesn't work. Here is what my terminal looks like:

```sh
$ git config --local user.name "myusername"
$ git config --local user.name
myusername
$ git config --local user.email "email@gmail.com"
$ git config --local user.email
myemail@gmail.com
$ git push
remote: Permission to myusername/myusername.github.io.git denied to otheraccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myusername/myusername.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a credential manager and it has credentials stored for a different account.  Those credentials are being used when you push, and the other account doesn't have access to that repo.

If you do have multiple accounts and want to use both, then you should use the [technique outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingHTTP) (there's also [one for SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH)).  If you just have credentials you don't want to use anymore, then you should [use the technique outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager) to do that.  Note that the latter technique is broken for Git Credential Manager for Windows, and you should see their issue tracker for a workaround.

You should also note that `user.name` has no effect on authentication whatsoever.  It is instead the name that you place in your commits, and is by convention a personal name (that is, the name other humans call you).  Git permits it to be almost any value, so a username is permitted but not customary.